# ¿Como concatenar dos diferentes tipos de char?

Tags: c++

Verán cree un sistema de upload que  codifica la imagen en base64 para enviarla por email, y el base64 de la imagen la devuelvo con un char y la estructura de email lo tengo con otro char diferente y el problema es que al intentar concatenar los dos diferentes chars me da error de código.

Un ejemplo del código que tengo es este:

```
#define FILENAME "..."
static const int CHARS = 76;
static const int ADD_SIZE = 7;
static const int SEND_BUF_SIZE = 54;
static char (*fileBuf)[CHARS];
bool LARGEFILE = true;

size_t read_file()
{
    FILE *hFile = NULL;
    size_t fileSize(0), len(0), buffer_size(0);
    char key = ' ';
    hFile = fopen(FILENAME, "rb");
    if (!hFile)
    {
        cout << "Archivo no encontrado!!" << endl;
        _getch();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fseek(hFile, 0, SEEK_END);
    fileSize = ftell(hFile);
    fseek(hFile, 0, SEEK_SET);

    if (fileSize > 256000)
    {
        cout << "Espere...\n"
             << endl;
        cout << "Para cancelar preciones 'X'\n"
             << endl;
        cout << "Para continuar preciones ENTER\n"
             << endl;
        key = _getch();
        if (tolower(key) == 'x')
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        LARGEFILE = true;
    }
    cout << "Codificando " FILENAME " espere..." << endl;

    int no_of_rows = fileSize / SEND_BUF_SIZE + 1;
    int charsize = (no_of_rows * 72) + (no_of_rows * 2);

    unsigned char *b64encode = new unsigned char[charsize];
    *b64encode = 0;
    base64_encode(hFile, b64encode, no_of_rows);
    string encoded_buf = (char *)b64encode;

    if (LARGEFILE == true)
        cout << "" << endl;
    fileBuf = new char[ADD_SIZE + no_of_rows][CHARS];
    buffer_size += strlen(fileBuf[len - 1]);
    int pos = 0;
    string sub_encoded_buf;
    for (int i = 0; i <= no_of_rows - 1; i++)
    {
        sub_encoded_buf = encoded_buf.substr(pos * 72, 72);
        sub_encoded_buf += "\r\n";
        strcpy(fileBuf[len++], sub_encoded_buf.c_str());
        buffer_size += sub_encoded_buf.size();
        pos++;
    }
    delete[] b64encode;
    return buffer_size;
}
const char *headers[] = {
    "Date: ...\r\n",
    "To: ...\r\n",
    "From: ...\r\n",
    "Cc: ...\r\n",
    "Subject: ...\r\n",
    "Content-Type: application/x-msdownload; name=\"" FILENAME "\"\r\n",
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n",
    "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" FILENAME "\"\r\n",
    fileBuf
}
```

Esta es el error me arroja la consola

```
cannot initialize an array element of type 'const char *' with an value of type 'char (*)[76]'
file
^---
```

Espero haberme explicado bien.

Comment: Ya me parecía rara esa línea... `static char (*file)[76] = NULL;` ¿Qué intentaste hacer? No le veo ningún sentido. ¿De dónde sale el 76 o qué significa?

Comment: @ArtEze lo que hice fue crear un sistema de subida de archivos que codifica a base64, para enviar un archivo adjunto por email y pasar el base64 mediante el char (*file)[76] y concatenarlo con char headers. No se si me explique bien

Comment: No, no se entendió nada. ¿Qué es `file`? En el código no aparece declarada la variable, y el 76 todavía no sé lo que es.

Comment: @ArtEze añadí la función completa de mi código, espero entiendas un poquito mas :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No estás intentando concatenar dos tipos de `char`, estás intentando...

... no tengo ni idea de lo que estás intentando, tu código no tiene sentido.

---

#### Primero, `*file`.

Para empezar tienes un puntero a una formación<sup>1</sup> de setenta y seis caracteres (`char`):

```
static char (*file)[76] = NULL;
```

Puedes hacer que este puntero contenga **la dirección de** cualquier formación de setenta y seis caracteres, ni uno más, ni uno menos:

```
char setenta_y_seis[76]{};
char dos[2]{};

file = &setenta_y_seis; // Correcto
file = &dos; // Incorrecto
```

#### Segundo ¿`new char[7 + filesize / n_rows][76]`?.

Para crear formaciones dinámicas en C++ debes usar el operador `new[]`, su formato es:

```
tipo *variable = new tipo[tamaño];
```

Opcionalmente puedes añadir un inicializador **entre llaves**:

```
tipo *variable = new tipo[tamaño]{valores};
```

El operador `new[]` devolverá un **puntero** del tipo de datos de la formación.

#### Tu error.

Recuerda que `*file` sólo puede contener la dirección de una formación de setenta y seis caracteres (`char`), por otro lado `new[]` devuelve un puntero al tipo de datos de la formación no un puntero al tipo de la formación: Una formación de setenta y seis caracteres tiene de tipo `char[76]`, el operador `new[]` devuelve el tipo `char *`.

Por otro lado, la línea que usas para llamar al operador `new[]` tiene una sintaxis incorrecta porque ¿defines dos veces el tamaño? No entiendo qué pretendías:

```
//              vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv <--- ¿Primer tamaño?
file = new char[7 + filesize / n_rows][76];
//                                     ^^ <--- ¿Segundo tamaño?
```

Si tu tamaño es prefijado (setenta y seis) no necesitas memoria dinámica, si tu tamaño se calcula en tiempo de ejecución, no necesitas un puntero a una formación de tamaño fijado (aunque tampoco necesitaras un puntero de ese tipo). En resumen no logro entender la misión de tu código, deduzco que quieres esto:

#### Solución:

```
static char *file = nullptr;

size_t read_file() {
    // código......
    file = new char[7 + filesize / n_rows]{}
    for (/* código */) {
          // output representa el base64 del archivo o imagen
         strcpy(file[len++], output.c_str());
    }
}
```

Pero aunque esto soluciona el problema, es un código propenso a errores y muy alejado de los estándares modernos (y además `file` está en el espacio estático, decir que es estático explícitamente es redundante), si tu objetivo es leer el contenido de un archivo y devolverlo, usa un contenedor de datos:

```
std::vector read_file() {
    std::vector resultado(7 + filesize / n_rows, 0);

    for (/* código */) {
          // output representa el base64 del archivo o imagen
         resultado[len++] = valor;
    }

    return resultado;
}
```

---

1. También conocida como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.

Comment: Crees que añadiendo el código completo(solo la función especifica) podrás entender algo?

Comment: ya añadí la función completa, espero entiendas un poquito mas lo que estoy intentando hacer :)

Comment: @EddyOtsutsuki creo que has quitado la línea que produce el error.

Comment: La linea que produce el error ahora es `fileBuf` al intentar concatenarla con `headers`

Comment: También me gustaría saber como puedo convertir la variable char fileBuf a string

Comment: @EddyOtsutsuki te falla por lo que ya he respondido: Tu código no tiene sentido, intentas igualar tipos que no son igualables e intentas crear una formación con dos tamaños.

Comment: Entonces como podría devolver el base64 completo como un string y agregarlo a la variable headers con la función c_str()

Comment: @EddyOtsutsuki ¿Es una pregunta o una afirmación?

Comment: Una pregunta, me falto añadir `?` lo siento

Comment: @EddyOtsutsuki lo tienes en el código de respuesta, yo he usado un 'std::vector', pero puedes hacer exáctamente lo mismo con un `std::string`.